# How manage a combobox dynamically using sbCustomSelect function of sparkbox

Tags: jquery

I need to manage a combobox dynamically (changing options dynamically), but I am not able to reinitialize the combobox. 
At start time the combo is filled in the ready function $(document).ready(function () :

The function used to set combobox options is sbCustomSelect() of sparkbox.
When a particular condition happens, I need to empty the combobox options and add new options. But after changes  two combo box are displayed: the old one with all starting options and a new combo with the new options that are added. 
Any idea? Thanks in advance....

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 0):

In index.html:

```
<div class="title">
<h2 class="">SR Ref  #<a href="javascript:" class="detailsSrRef"></a></h2>
<select class="event detailsEvents" data-role="none" id="selEvent">
</select>
</div>
```

In script.js there is the initialization in ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

.....

var serviceRequestDetailsController = new  .ServiceRequestDetailsController();
serviceRequestDetailsController.setEventControllers([
    new AcceptEventController(),
    new RejectEventController(),
    new TravelToMaterialEventController(),
    new TravelToCustomerEventController(),
    new ArrivedAtCustomerEventController(),
    new ValidateOOSEventController(),
    new CompleteActionPlanEventController(),
    new ReturnPartsEventController(),
    new AddTextEventController(),
    new ExceptionEventController(),
    new FixAcceptedEventController()
]);

.....

}
```

In action.js:

```
var html = '<option data-placeholder="true" >Select Event</option>';
    for (var idx = 0; idx < eventControllers.length; idx++) {
        //Fix
      if (!(eventControllers[idx].getEventName() ==  com.ibm.client.dto.ServiceRequest.TRAVEL_TO_MATERIALS_STATUS))
if (!(eventControllers[idx].getEventName() == com.ibm.client.dto.ServiceRequest.PARTS_RETURNED_STATUS))
if (!(eventControllers[idx].getEventName() == com.ibm.client.dto.ServiceRequest.FIX_ACCEPTED_STATUS))   
html += '<option value="' + utility.htmlEncode(eventControllers[idx].getEventName()) + '">' +
            utility.htmlEncode(eventControllers[idx].getEventName()) + '</option>'
}

$('.detailsEvents').each(function(){
$(this).html(html);
$(this).change(function() {
var value = $(this).find(":selected").val();
$(this).sbCustomSelect();
});
```

These are my changes to add a new option in a function of action.js:

```
if (logicalStatus=="TAK"){

$('#selEvent').empty();
var newOption=$('<option value="' + utility.htmlEncod  (com.ibm.client.dto.ServiceRequest.ADD_TEXT_STATUS) + '">' +
                  utility.htmlEncode   (com.ibm.client.dto.ServiceRequest.ADD_TEXT_STATUS) + '</option>');          
    $('#selEvent').append(newOption);
}
```

I hope that is clear because the code is not in a single file.